# How to fix subdivide surface buttholes?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make a smooth circle using subdivision surface but every time I go about it the top and bottom begin to distort into a semi-anus-looking shape and I'm not very fond of it.

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening (I'm relatively new to blender) and I can't find any fix. Is there any way to fix this or do I just work with a subdivided cube instead?

Comment: They are caused by the "poles" (intersection of tri's) at the top and bottom - you are correct, subdivided cube is the best way to avoid it - use a _Subdivision Surface Modifier_ (level 2 at least) and a _Cast Modifier_ with the _Factor_ set to 1

Comment: Additionally you can get a QuadSphere by enabling the [Extra Objects Addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html) and adding a Round Cube object.